# getElementById does not call the HTML ID

Tags: javascript, html

I have a folder with two files each, once the HTML file, and once the JS file to make everything clearer. My problem now is that I try to access an ID within the HTML file with the getElementById but this doesn't seem to work.

```js
var score = 0;

score = score + 1;
document.getElementById("score").outerHTML = score;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Clicker Game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
        <script src="code.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Cookies: <span id="score">0</span></p>
        <img src="images/cookie.png" height="256px" width="256px">
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to call the ID "score" in the HTML file to make sure that when I start the HTML file locally the number changes from 0 to 1.

Comment: Your JavaScript code will run *once*. You have to hook it up as an event handler.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bhyd8ax5/ looks OK to me? :)

Comment: Your code is effectively fine. However you really want to be updating innerHtml or text, **not** outer HTML as you will lose the targeted tag. If you are not seeing the number change, check to see if the javascript file is loading correctly in the consoe and network tab in your browsers developer tools

Answer (score 0):

Click on the number in the HTML file, which will change the value. You cannot change the value without a trigger in the HTML. Something needs to be clicked or changed for the value to appear.
Edit: And don't grab the outerHTML of the element. You are erasing the whole `score` span and replacing it with the count. Use `textContent` instead.

```js
let elem = document.querySelector("#score");

elem.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  elem.textContent = Number(elem.textContent) + 1;
})
```

```css
#score {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Clicker Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
  <script src="code.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Cookies: <span id="score">0</span></p>
  <img src="images/cookie.png" height="256px" width="256px">
</body>

</html>
```